Locked dead tuples PostGres
I'm dealing with a situation of dead tuples on an extremely busy environment. Post maintenance, everything performs optimally but within a couple days query execution times increase to about 90%. I found that this is because the dead tuples are growing so rapidly that the autovacuum is actually consuming all the IOPS.
To address this temporarily while working on long running queries, i'm trying to do some vacuum analyze cadence though i'm stuck:
vacuum (analyze, verbose) example_table;
INFO:  vacuuming "public.example_table"
INFO:  index "example_table_id" now contains 22659995 row versions in 116780 pages
DETAIL:  0 index row versions were removed.
0 index pages were newly deleted.
35548 index pages are currently deleted, of which 0 are currently reusable.
CPU: user: 0.18 s, system: 0.23 s, elapsed: 0.43 s.
INFO:  table "example_table": found 0 removable, 24188603 nonremovable row versions in 715448 out of 760196 pages
DETAIL:  23675630 dead row versions cannot be removed yet, oldest xmin: 1009220356
Skipped 0 pages due to buffer pins, 44748 frozen pages.
CPU: user: 2.76 s, system: 1.67 s, elapsed: 4.49 s.
INFO:  vacuuming "pg_toast.pg_toast_1186989633"
INFO:  table "pg_toast_1186989633": found 0 removable, 0 nonremovable row versions in 0 out of 0 pages
DETAIL:  0 dead row versions cannot be removed yet, oldest xmin: 1009220356
Skipped 0 pages due to buffer pins, 0 frozen pages.
CPU: user: 0.00 s, system: 0.00 s, elapsed: 0.00 s.
INFO:  analyzing "public.example_table"
INFO:  "example_table": scanned 30000 of 760196 pages, containing 21249 live rows and 934037 dead rows; 21249 rows in sample, 538447 estimated total rows
VACUUM

             tablename             | livetuples | deadtuples | deadpercent
             example_table         |     542900 |   23675630 |       97.76`

You can see from the above, that it cant remove any of these dead tuples. There is absolutely nothing hitting this table directly currently so i'm a little lost as to what may be going on. I have also attempted to do a VACUUM FULL with success and no blocking, which rebuilt the table with the same number of dead tuples.
anyone know how to tackle something like this ? i feel like im hunting a ghost
In regards to long transactions, there is many... some running for 20+ hours actually (introducing timeout soon), but again, none that are touching this table directly.

checked for anything hitting this table
checked through IDLE queries for anything hitting this table
did a reindex incase there is some type of corruption
No prepared transactions
No replication slots on this instance
No standby server

EDIT: Not sure why my thread was locked and marked as duplicate... i have mentioned above all the checks performed which is actually from the thread marked as duplicate for:
Postgres: "vacuum" command does not clean up dead tuples

There is absolutely nothing hitting this table directly How come it even has tuples if nothing is hitting this table? If nothing is using this table, you could even drop it and your problem is gone.

@FrankHeikens, there is nothing hitting this table "currently". I cant drop this table as its needed. guess i should update my post to reflect currently
